Find unique value and row data through Powershell using a CSV file
I may not have found the answer (even though it is available), but this is what I am looking for.  There are four columns in a CSV file, and I need to display the row using the user ID.  Here is the data:
Timestamp           Location    ID      Name
01/01/2024 00:02    London      171320  Derek Peters
01/02/2024 00:02    London      114554  Jon Adams
01/02/2024 01:02    Manchester  680283  Nigel Terry
02/02/2024 00:02    London      210144  Jenny Smith
03/02/2024 00:02    London      171320  Derek Peters
03/02/2024 00:02    Manchester  265712  Amanda Lort
04/02/2024 00:02    Manchester  114554  Jon Adams
05/02/2024 00:02    Manchester  680283  Nigel Terry
06/02/2024 00:02    Coventry    171320  Derek Peters
06/02/2024 00:02    Coventry    206665  Stevie Eddies
07/02/2024 00:02    Coventry    171320  Derek Peters

The output I am look for is:
ID        Location    Count
171320    London      2
          Coventry    2
114554    London      1
          Manchester  1
680283    Manchester  2
210144    London      1
265712    Manchester  1
206665    Coventry    1


what have you tried yet?

Is input file Comma Delimited, Fix Space, Or Tab Delimited?

Please copy and paste the code you are trying to make work into the question as text.  Include any error messages. No pictures. Describe what is happening and what you want to happen.

$Csv |
Group-Object ID, Location |
select @{ N = 'ID' ; E = {$_.Name.Split(', ')[0]} }, @{ N = 'Location' ; E = {$_.Name.Split(', ')[-1]} }, 'Count'


The answer from @Someone works. This does, too. It uses Group-Object, then regexes to create calculated properties.
Import-Csv -Path .\GroupPlaces.csv |
    Group-Object -Property Location,ID |
    Select-Object @{n='ID';e={$_.Name -replace '^.*, '}},
        @{n='Location';e={$_.Name -replace ',.*'}},
        Count

